# Ingress not routing the traffic to the exact service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

i need your help with the ingress config
actualy i had an fqdn pointed to the ip adress of my nginx ingress controller and put it as a host name,i perfectly matched the ingress ressources to my ingress controller but the traffic didn't route and the app didn't work
[image]

when i troubleshhoded i found that the pod ip is perfectly connecting to the service and the ingress is seeing the my manipmcv service, i doubted that it may be the ressource is not from nginx controller but i found that it is from the nginx .

Comment: Just to chekc your ingress is in ingress-Nginx namespace while the service `manipmcv service` is also in the same namespace ?

Comment: ye both are in the same namespace

Comment: please share exact commands and errors you face so the issue might be well understood and reproduced

Comment: when i described the status of my pods services and even the ingres are all in a healthy state, even more when described the ingress it showed me the hostname and it is pointed to the service with the same pod ip of my deploment , I also verified if the fqdn i wrote as a host name matches with the ip of the ingress controller i found that they match ..match i don't know how the traffic is not routed and the app didn' work ( btw without ingress the apps runs perfectly but when i pass them throw my ingress they did not)

Comment: what error you get when you hit URL or host in browser ? hope you are also appending `/app1`

Comment: did you verify by port forwarding service? there is no issue with that ? also checked logs of nginx ingress controller ?

Comment: when hit url in the browser it tells me time out error

Comment: @HarshManvar the port is configured on 80 as default but i juste notice when i asked for logs it tells me no ressources are found in this namespace

Comment: in your ingress there is portname set did you check nginx igress support that version you are running ? instead of port Number in ingress sysntax.

Comment: @HarshManvar even when i change it to port number it doesn't work.any other idea

Comment: what is in logs of nginx ingress controller it self ? share that in question.

Comment: @bouthaynahamdi what you shared is not enough for understanding the problem. The exact commands you use, errors you face, logs, etc... are required in order to help you effectively.